# Lendo arquivo CSV acentuado em Python?

Tags: python, csv

estou aprendendo python3 e acabei empacando na questão de ler um arquivo csv simples que contém o caracter 'à'.
Já tentei usar decode, encode que encontrei pela internet mas nada parece funcionar, sempre é impresso como '\xc3\xa0'.
Lembrando que utilizo o sublime para editar o código e rodar o mesmo.

```
import csv

with open('teste.csv', 'r') as ficheiro:
    reader = csv.reader(ficheiro, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

O arquivo teste.csv:

```
batata;14;True
pàtato;19;False
papa;10;False
```

O erro:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mine/Desktop/testando csv.py", line 5, in <module>
    for row in reader:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Aguardo ajuda.

Answer (score 7):

Depende de qual codificação salvou o arquivo `.csv`

> **Note:** no python 2 o `csv` só suporta ASCII

### UTF-8

Se o arquivo `.csv` estiver salvo como UTF-8 pode fazer conforme a [documentação do Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples):

```
import csv

with open('teste.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Se o arquivo .csv não estiver em UTF-8 vai ocorrer um erro semelhante a isto:

> ```
> C:\Users\guilherme\Desktop>python testcsv.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "testcsv.py", line 5, in <module>
>     for row in reader:
>   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: invalid
> continuation byte
> ```

Se estiver tudo correto irá ficar assim:

[image: windows]

Se for um problema em um terminal de um ambiente like-unix (por exemplo Mac e linux) aplique isto (acredito que o documento também tem que estar salvo em *UTF-8 sem BOM*):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv

with open('teste.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

### Latin1

Se o arquivo estiver salvo em ANSI, ou latin1 ou *windows-1252* ou iso-8859-1 (eles são "compatíveis") pode setar `encoding='latin-1'` (apesar que no Python3 no Windows não foi preciso), deve ficar assim:

```
import csv

with open('teste.csv', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Já havia tentado isso e continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: @LucasFabio atualizei a resposta, veja se resolve

Comment: Realmente isso é estranho não estar a funcionar, expimenta colocar também esta sugestão Guilherme, http://ideone.com/D8LF9o , não usar o modulo csv... Duvido que seja disso mas não o Lucas não perde nada em tentar